# Certification/Course for software designer/architecture

Tags: architecture

After being a software developer for 7+ years, I think it is time for me to take my programming to the next level. I am thinking in terms of a designer or an architect.

Is there a certification/course available for designer/architect? I do agree that a certification/course will not make me a good designer/architect, but it will go on my resume. IMO it will also provide me with a platform for me to dig deeper.

Please advise me a Certification or a Course for software designer/architect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Part of the question, you already answered that Certification is not the only criteria to become a better architecture or designer. You must have real architectural experience by designing some real world application.

I think, you can start by

1- Designing a component from ground 0 this may be in your current project, a module, a small application.

2- Thinking in terms of more efficient Algorithms, design procedure, patterns

3- Be in touch with latest technology, platform etc.

4- Learning more deployment patterns.

5- Learning more about data storage and retrieval systems.

6- Start participating in forums, Q&A sites like SO

7- Start writing small technical papers.

There are more points beyond the ones mentioned above, but these points are surely a starting point for the long journey to be an architect.

Plus, work under a senior architect / architect as a Technical Lead or Junior Architect will also act as a boost.

Finally, there are certain certifications by the industry leaders like Microsoft, IBM, and others. One of the certifications which I know is

**MCA (Micorsoft Certiifed Architect)**

But this certification  has some predefined criterias like (Min 10 Yrs work ex etc..)

Comment: Micorsoft - Certiifed ;- excellent typo

Answer (score 15):

Before thinking about certificate, learn Design well,

- I think the basis of design described
  by **[Uncle Bob Martin principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)**.
- learn about **[Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29)** .
- There are some certificates like MCA,
  but I think one should prefer to
  participate in **[thoughtworks](http://www.thoughtworks.com/thoughtworks-university)**
  university, or other international and
  great developers workshops.

Comment: +1 for "Uncle Bob Martin principles"

Comment: +1 for "Uncle Bob Martin principles" link

Answer (score 6):

The "International Software Architecture Qualification Board" ([www.isaqb.org](http://www.isaqb.org)) provides a vendor- and technology-neutral curriculum on their website.

It explains the required knowledge and abilities of software architects.

Several levels of certification are available.

Answer (score 4):

For a **vendor neutral** and technology agnostic software architecture certification track, take a look at [SEI training and certificates](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/go/architecture-curriculum).

For **vendor neutral but SOA-specific** software architecture certification, take a look at [SOASchool](http://soaschool.com/certifications/architect).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what has already been mentioned (Microsoft Certified Architect) - There's another that is offered by Sun (oracle..). It's known as "Sun Certified Enterprise Architect" and has now been rebranded as "Oracle Certified Master, Java EE 5 Enterprise Architect"

But nothing comes close to designing real world solutions. These certifications help in exploring the options and patterns, and are very valuable - but the real test comes in how this knowledge is applied in real world.

Hope it helps.
All the best!